# Animation lags while using a support Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-cardview

I am using the support.v7 Cardview and when i click on them i made a animation so the cardview expands to show more Information.
This worked fine and smooth, but now i add a toolbar as Support actionbar and now the Animation is laggy and i have no idea why:

I use this to expand a cardview

```
public  void expand(final View v,final View vi) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,                                         
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = getHeight((ListView)v);
    v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation()
    {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            vi.setAlpha(1-interpolatedTime*10);
            v.setAlpha(1-vi.getAlpha());
            double heigt = -(targetHeight / (interpolatedTime + 1)) + targetHeight;
            v.getLayoutParams().height =new Double(heigt*2).intValue();

            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration(750);
    v.startAnimation(a);
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            v.getLayoutParams().height=targetHeight;
            v.requestLayout();
            vi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    },a.getDuration()+100);

}
```

and this is how i create the toolbar:

toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

```
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("CocktailListe");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("Deine Lieblingscocktails in einer app");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_main));
    toolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_actionbar_secondary));
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(db.getActionbarColor()));
```

I´m pretty stuck and have no idea why it lags while using the toolbar, i hope someone can help